# Handling Async Vue Prop

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am loading in props to my component that are grabbing data off a server in an async function.
In the component itself, displaying the data via `{{ id }}` in the template works fine.

But when I try to use it in a computed property or watch it for any changes, it returns a

`Action.vue:51 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: id is not defined`

I've tried adding a default value of 0 to the prop id, but the same error occurs, I can't seem to figure out any way to work with this prop data other than simply loading it as it is in the template.

Comment: It seems you forgot to prepend `this.` to `id` inside your computed property / watcher. Could you show your Action.vue?

Comment: Ah! As I'm using the new ```<script setup>``` method, I thought that I can just use the props as it is, I found that I have to define a new const to hold the props after using ```defineProps``` to declare it. Thank you for your reminder!